# Find the nullity of the transformation $T(f)=f-f'$ from $C^\infty$ to $C^\infty$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the kernel is defined as $T(f)=0$ or $f-f'=0$ which has solutions $ae^x$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$. But how do we define the dimension of the kernel in this case? Is it just equal to $1$?

Comment: All elements in the kernel are multiples of one nonzero element of the kernel. Yes, that means $\dim \ker T = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\ker T=\operatorname{span}(x\mapsto e^x)$ so $(x\mapsto e^x)$ is a basis for the kernel of $T$ and then the nullity of $T$ is $1$.